# How can I view the superblock of an XFS partition?

Tags: xfs, superblock

I know that EXT superblock information can be found using `dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1`, but what is the XFS equivalent of this? The best I have found so far is `xfs_info /dev/sda1`, but this doesn't seem to produce nearly as much information as can be gotten with an EXT filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in the [official documentation](http://xfs.org/docs/xfsdocs-xml-dev/XFS_Filesystem_Structure/tmp/en-US/html/Allocation_Groups.html#Superblocks). Looks like the filesystem cannot be mounted.

```
$ sudo xfs_db /dev/sda1
xfs_db> sb
xfs_db> p
magicnum = 0x58465342
blocksize = 4096
dblocks = 62769952
rblocks = 0
```

Comment: What does sb do?

Comment: I am guessing `sb` selects the superblock. `p` prints the superblock.

Comment: no need to [guess](https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/xfs_db.html)